# How to use <Link> to change pathname of location with HashRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I use HashRouter. Say I want to navigate to `http://localhost:8089/abc/#/home`, I could use `window.history.pushState({}, '', 'http://localhost:8089/abc/#/home')` to do it.

My question is how to use `<Link>` api of react-router to do the same navigation.
I tried `<Link to="/#/home">`, it's not work.

Qestion 2: 
I got a url `http://localhost:8089/abc/#/app1`, and I want to navigate to `http://localhost:8089/aaa/#/home`. I tried `<Link to="/aaa/#/home">`, but it navigate to the url `http://localhost:8089/abc/#/aaa/#/home`

Here's the router config:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, HashRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../containers/app';


class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter basename="/">
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
            </HashRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default Routes;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `<Link to="/home">`?

Comment: Did you configure history package on your Router?

Comment: @HamedNavabian I added the code of router config.

Comment: @Jackson yes, it will navigate to `http://localhost:8089/#/home`, and I want to navigate to `http://localhost:8089/abc/#/home`

Comment: `react-router-dom` cares about the route after your domain, so you have to use `/abc/#/home` not `/#/home`

Comment: @asmaa I added Question 2 in the description. It seems that the <Link> only change the part of url that after the `#` tag. However, I want to change pathname of the url.

Comment: so what is your baseURL ?

Comment: @asmaa I am sorry. It's a little complicate, I use single-spa which use the first level pathname to switch between child apps. So I want to change the base url.

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look please :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `Link`, you can try:

```
<Link to="/abc/#/home/" />
```

if you want to use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

 function Home() {
     let history = useHistory();

     function handleClick() {
         history.push("/abc/#/home");
     }
 }
```

Edit:
I know how to use `Router` and `Switch` instead of using `HashRouter`

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> // localhost:8089/
    <Route exact path="/abc/home" component={Home2} /> // localhost:8089/abc/home
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

then you can use Link as above

Comment: Thanks. And please tell me how to make the baseURL `http://localhost:8089/` only too?

Answer (score -1):

hey use **Linking** instead firstly `import Linking fro react-native;`

and then implemented the following method.

```
onPress={() =>  Linking.openURL("URL of page // path of page").catch(err =>
                  console.error("Couldn't load page", err),
                )  }
```

Hope it hekps , Feel free for Doubts.